# Set text value to current year on window load

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the IntegerUpDown control which you can read about here: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown&referringTitle=Home

Basically a textbox with spinner controls.

What I want to do is, when the program starts up, to have the current year, with `yyyy` format, displayed in the control. Now, I can do this in code behind easily like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        YearEditSpin.Value = DateTime.Now.Year;
    }
```

But I'm having issues getting it to work using just the xaml.

I tried various combinations of this:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="YearEditSpin" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='yyyy'}"/>
```

But it either shows up blank or says I need a path/two-way binding. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Not sure why you wanna do this with just XAML. You're better off creating a property on the datacontext and binding to that instead. Set the default value of the property to be `DateTime.Now.Year`.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to do two way bind to a static source. 
you may need to bind to a property which has a set accessor  .

Comment: Even if it's just a one-time bind? As in, only when the window is loaded?

Comment: Replace this code .Setting the Binding mode to OneWay.  <xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="YearEditSpin" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='yyyy'}"/>

Comment: But if i understand Correctly your control will be used to increment and decrement the year. So setting it to oneway binding wont be a right solution.